# How do I track facebook status posts from my android app

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm creating an android app from which users can share some data on their facebook. I want to track all these statuses (might involve pictures too). Is there a way by which I can get this info from the user's facebook account? I'm using facebook sdk 4.3

Comment: what do you mean by track

Comment: I mean I want to get all the status/pictures that the user has shared on facebook and re-post it on my app's common wall.

Comment: You can do it using graph api